# How can I change the line width of the spy-on node in tikz spy library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

is there an option to change the line width of the spy-on node, i.e. the node that appears on the image, in the tikz spy library?

Comment: Does [Increase the thickness of node border in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106742) help?

Comment: I tried that already in every possible way, but spy seems to ignore it. For example \spy[blue] paints the line blue, but \spy[thick] has no effect.

Comment: This is quite a hack http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55374/change-draw-color-in-a-clipped-region-in-tikz-pgf. I would suggest get over it and stay away. It's not worth it:)

Comment: Whoa I got the question completely wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can’t use `\spy[thick]` because

1. the options of `\spy` are actually used on a scope and
2. the `every spy on node` style includes already `very thin` (`.2pt`) which overwrites the `thick` of the scope from `\spy`.

You will need to use the `every spy on node` style and alter it. For every spy in the current scope you can use it in `spy using outlines`, e.g.

```
spy using outlines={…, every spy on node/.append style={thin}}
```

or directly on the `\spy` with

```
\spy [every spy on node/.append style={ultra thick}] …;
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies,
    every spy on node/.append style={thin}}]
\draw [decoration={name=Koch curve type 1}] decorate
  { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
\spy [red]            on (1.6,0.3) in node [left]  at (3.5,-1.25);
\spy [blue, size=1cm] on (  1,  1) in node [right] at (  0,-1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  spy using outlines={circle, magnification=4, size=2cm, connect spies}]
\draw [decoration={name=Koch curve type 1}] decorate
  { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
\spy [red, every spy on node/.append style={ultra thick}]
  on (1.6,0.3) in node [left]  at (3.5,-1.25);
\spy [blue, size=1cm]
  on (  1,  1) in node [right] at (  0,-1.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image]