# How to name a spypoint in a tikzfigure to access it via node name

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, spy

I want to access two spypoints in a `tikzpicture` environment via node name. Unfortunately, naming the spypoint doesn't seem to work in the same way as it does for the magnifyglass node.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4, connect spies}]

        \begin{axis}[%
            height=5cm,%
            width=10cm, %
            ymin=-1, ymax=21, %
            xmin=0, xmax=1000, %
            xticklabels={},%
            ytick={0, 10, 20}, %
            name=first,%
            ]

            \coordinate (spypoint1) at (axis cs:30,10);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass1) at (axis cs:300,3.3);

            \coordinate (spypoint2) at (axis cs:850,3.3);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass2) at (axis cs:650,3.4);

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
            height=4cm,%
            width=10cm, %
            ymin=-1, ymax=1, %
            xmin=0, xmax=1000, %
                at={(first.below south west)}, yshift=-0.1cm,  anchor=north west, %
            ]

            \coordinate (spypoint3) at (axis cs:30,0);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass3) at (axis cs:300,0.4);

            \coordinate (spypoint4) at (axis cs:850,-0.1);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass4) at (axis cs:600,-0.4);

        \end{axis}

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=20mm, name=a1] on (spypoint1)
            in node [fill=white,name=a] at (magnifyglass1);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=22mm] on (spypoint2)
            in node [fill=white,name=b] at (magnifyglass2);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=20mm, name=c1] on (spypoint3)
            in node [fill=white,name=c] at (magnifyglass3);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=22mm] on (spypoint4)
            in node [fill=white,name=d] at (magnifyglass4);

        \end{scope}

        \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[dashed] (c) -- (d);

        \draw[red] (a1) -- (c1);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the connections for `\draw (a) -- (b)` and `(c) -- (d)` work fine, while the connection `(a1) -- (c1)` doesn't work. I get the error message

> No shape named a1 is known.

and the same for `(c1)`.

Without the `\draw[red] (a1) -- (c1);` line, the picture looks as follows. The red line resembles what my expected result of adding the line would be

[image: picture with expected line in red]

Can anyone tell me the correct way to name the spypoint node? I didn't find anything in the `pgfplots` or `tikz` manual. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Connect `spypoint1` with `spypoint3`?

Comment: My goal is to connect the lower edges of `spypoint1` with the upper edges of `spypoint3` and the same for `spypoint2` and `spypoint4`. So I thought, if I could access the nodes via names, I could use something like `\draw (spypoint1.south west) -- (spypoint3.north west)`. Unfortunately I already fail at naming the `spypoint` nodes as it seems.

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SX. According to the last paragraph in section 68.3 in the [`pgfmanual` on page 741 (v3.0.1a)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=741) this should be possible using the `every spy on node` style. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on [Stefan Pinnow's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326452/how-to-name-a-spypoint-in-a-tikzfigure-to-access-it-via-node-name/326591#comment798676_326452), and using this answer: [How can I change the line width of the spy-on node in tikz spy library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145905/102121), here is how a `spy on` node can be named (it's quite counterintuitive to modify an `every` style locally for one node but it's what Tantau suggests in the manual).

```
        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=20mm, every spy on node/.append style={name=a1}] on (spypoint1)
            in node [fill=white,name=a] at (magnifyglass1);
```

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every spy on node/.style={name}]

        \begin{scope}[spy using outlines={rectangle, magnification=4, connect spies}]

        \begin{axis}[%
            height=5cm,%
            width=10cm, %
            ymin=-1, ymax=21, %
            xmin=0, xmax=1000, %
            xticklabels={},%
            ytick={0, 10, 20}, %
            name=first,%
            ]

            \coordinate (spypoint1) at (axis cs:30,10);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass1) at (axis cs:300,3.3);

            \coordinate (spypoint2) at (axis cs:850,3.3);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass2) at (axis cs:650,3.4);

        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[%
            height=4cm,%
            width=10cm, %
            ymin=-1, ymax=1, %
            xmin=0, xmax=1000, %
                at={(first.below south west)}, yshift=-0.1cm,  anchor=north west, %
            ]

            \coordinate (spypoint3) at (axis cs:30,0);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass3) at (axis cs:300,0.4);

            \coordinate (spypoint4) at (axis cs:850,-0.1);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass4) at (axis cs:600,-0.4);

        \end{axis}

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=20mm, every spy on node/.append style={name=a1}] on (spypoint1)
            in node [fill=white,name=a] at (magnifyglass1);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=22mm] on (spypoint2)
            in node [fill=white,name=b] at (magnifyglass2);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=20mm, every spy on node/.append style={name=c1}] on (spypoint3)
            in node [fill=white,name=c] at (magnifyglass3);

        \spy [black, height=12mm, width=22mm] on (spypoint4)
            in node [fill=white,name=d] at (magnifyglass4);

        \end{scope}

        \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[dashed] (c) -- (d);

        \draw[red] (a1) -- (c1);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is the same answer as [Christoph Frings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326586/95441)' one, but I "optimized" it a bit. The main change is that I introduced the new style `Name` as a shorthand for `every spy on node/.append style`. For the rest have a look at the comments in the code.

---

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    \tikzset{
        % define shorthand key/style to give spy-on node names
        Name/.style={
            every spy on node/.append style={
                name=#1,
            },
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=5cm,
            width=10cm,
            ymin=-1,ymax=21,
            xmin=0,xmax=1000,
            xticklabels={},
            ytick={0,10,20},
            name=first,
        ]
            \coordinate (spypoint1)     at (axis cs:30,10);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass1) at (axis cs:300,3.3);

            \coordinate (spypoint2)     at (axis cs:850,3.3);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass2) at (axis cs:650,3.4);
        \end{axis}

        \begin{axis}[
            height=4cm,
            width=10cm,
            ymin=-1,ymax=1,
            xmin=0,xmax=1000,
            at={(first.below south west)},
            yshift=-0.1cm,
            anchor=north west,
        ]
            \coordinate (spypoint3)     at (axis cs:30,0);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass3) at (axis cs:300,0.4);

            \coordinate (spypoint4)     at (axis cs:850,-0.1);
            \coordinate (magnifyglass4) at (axis cs:600,-0.4);
        \end{axis}

        % moved begin of scope here
        \begin{scope}[
            spy using outlines={%
                rectangle,
                magnification=4,
                connect spies,
                %
                % moved other common keys here
                black,
                height=12mm,
                width=20mm,
            },
        ]
            \spy [Name=a1] on (spypoint1)
                in node [fill=white,name=a] at (magnifyglass1);

            \spy [width=22mm] on (spypoint2)
                in node [fill=white,name=b] at (magnifyglass2);

            \spy [Name=c1] on (spypoint3)
                in node [fill=white,name=c] at (magnifyglass3);

            \spy [width=22mm] on (spypoint4)
                in node [fill=white,name=d] at (magnifyglass4);

        \end{scope}

        \draw[dashed] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[dashed] (c) -- (d);

        \draw[red] (a1) -- (c1);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course this also results in your desired output.

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you very much! This comes in very handy as I will need it at multiple occasions.

Comment: You are welcome. If you find our answers useful, you could thank us by upvoting our answers (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it).